# Struggling to Install Pip and Django on Windows 10

Tags: python, django, installation

Hi ultimately I'm trying to install django on my computer, but I'm unable to do this as the when I run pip in the command line I get the following error message:

`''pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.'`

I've added the following locations to my path environment:

'`C:\Python37-32;C:\Python37-32\Lib\site-packages;C:\Python37-32\Scripts'`

I've also tried to reinstall pip using 'py -3.7 -m ensurepip -U --default-pip', but then I get the following error message:

`'Requirement already up-to-date: setuptools in c:\users\tom_p\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (40.6.3)
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in c:\users\tom_p\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (18.1)
spyder 3.3.2 requires pyqt5<5.10; python_version >= "3", which is not installed.
xlwings 0.15.1 has requirement pywin32>=224, but you'll have pywin32 223 which is incompatible.'`

I'm new to this so I'm struggling with the install and I'm confused by the fact pip is in C:\Python37-32\Scripts, but the above error seems to be looking in the anaconda folder. The only reason I installed anaconda was to use the Spyder IDE.

I've installed python 3.7 32-bit on my Windows 10, any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: The version is 3.7.2, isn't that the latest release?

Comment: Conda is recommended to start using python on windows: https://conda.io/miniconda.html

Comment: If you open up a new command prompt and run `echo %PATH%` do you see `C:\Python37-32\Scripts` in the list?

Comment: do you use pip inside your project directory?

Comment: @WillKeeling Yes I can see that location, but it was enclosed by speech marks along with two other python locations. I've since separated each of these three file locations out in the path environmental, but I'm not sure if theyshould be separated or not?

Comment: @Annabelle thanks for pointing this out. I think I may have been trying to call pip from within python rather than from my working directory before, as now when I call pip I don't see an error

Answer (score 0):

You can see what pythons are available to you with:

```
py -0p
```

which, *on Windows*, will display a list of the available python versions.

You should then be able to use:

```
py -mpip install django
```

Which will install to the default, (highest version), of Python or if you need to install to a specific version you can use:

```
py -3.7-64 -mpip install django
```

to install to 64 bit python version 3.7 (if you have them available you can specify other versions as `py -`*m*`.`*n*`-`*bl* where *m* is the major version (2/3), *n* is the minor and *bl* is one of 64/32 for the bit length.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Steve I've just used the below code which seemed to work, as I was told django 2.1.5 successfully installed and I can find a django.js application on my computer.

`py -3.7-32 -mpip install django`

However, I'm unable to open this application and when I run the below code I'm seeing the error message: 'C:\Users\tom_p\Anaconda3\python.exe: No module named django'

`py -m django --version`

I tried to install the 64 bit version of django, but that gave an error. The pythons that are available to me are:

`-3.7-64        C:\Users\tom_p\Anaconda3\python.exe *
 -3.7-32        C:\Python37-32\python.exe`